# Alternative loop syntax error

Tags: php, loop

I'm trying to minimize my code and have put together this little snippet, it doesn't seem to work however. What am I missing?

```
query_posts( 'year=2011' );
if ( have_posts() );
while ( have_posts() );
echo 'test';
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
endif;
```

Comment: Perhaps "shortcodes" is not the right word for it. I meant leaving out in this case the curly brackets in the if and while statements.
What is the word for optimizing like this? :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with shortcodes...

Comment: It's just referred to as an [alternative syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for loops.

Comment: Closing voting as off-topic as this is a simple PHP syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using semicolons when you should be using colons after the `if` and the `while` :)

```
query_posts( 'year=2011' );
if ( have_posts() ):
    while ( have_posts() ):
        the_post();
        the_title();
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
endif;
```

That works just fine.